# Alternative parameter type in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, scenarios

I have the following Cucumber step and I want to test it for 1st, 2nd, 3rd ... etc item.

`When user makes a request for the 1st item`

An here is its implementation

`@When("user makes a request for the {int}st/nd/rd/th item")`

Seems like its correct but the test does not run and I get error `Parameter types cannot be alternative: ...`
What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatives are separated by whitespace so the parameter binds strongly into the alternative. So it is expecting `{int}st` or `nd` or `rd` or `th`.

You will have to use regular expression. E.g:

```
^user makes a request for the (\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th) item$
```